# How generic methods gets instantiated in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

Suppose I've a generic method as:

```
void Fun<T>(FunArg arg) {}
```

Are `this.Fun<Feature>` and `this.Fun<Category>` different instantiations of the generic method?

In general, how does the generic method get instantiated? Different generic argument produces different method, or same method along with different metadata which is used at runtime?

Please support your answer with some quote(s) from the language specification.

Also, suppose I did these:

```
client.SomeEvent += this.Fun<Feature>;   //line1
client.SomeEvent += this.Fun<Category>;  //line2
client.SomeEvent += this.Fun<Result>;    //line3
```

then later on,

```
client.SomeEvent -= this.Fun<Feature>;   //lineX
```

Does the `lineX` undo the thing which I did at `line1`? Or it depends on somethig else also?

Comment: That's not valid code to start with. You can't use a method group conversion as the target of a `var` declaration. Present valid code, and we can give a better answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Removed that part.

Comment: So at this point, what *exactly* do you mean by an "instantiation"? The clearer you can be in your question, the clearer your answer can be.

Comment: @JonSkeet: By *instantiation*, I meant different method at runtime. Two *instantiations* of the generic method means two different and separate methods at runtime which doesn't share anything.

Comment: @Nawaz re your update; yes `lineX` creates a new delegate instance using `Fun<Feature>` (a specific, known-T, method); then delegate subtraction applies, which (because it is the same `MethodInfo` and same instance) cancels out the first `Fun<Feature>` in the delegate list, leaving `Fun<Category>` and `Fun<Result>`

Comment: @Nawaz "two different methods at runtime which doesn't share anything" is tricky.... each `T` is a separate `MethodInfo`, but there could still be some "sharing" (i.e. JIT sharing) - and they certainly share the same generic declaration.

Comment: @Nawaz: That's still not exact. Your update shows delegate objects - we can answer about that in particular, but if you mean more generally, you'd need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't know how to ask that. I don't know much C# terminologies and their meanings. Anyway, let me try again: I basically I want to know if I can assume that `Fun<Feature>()` is different from `Fun<Category>()` in the same way as `FunFeature()` is different from `FunCategory()`. Can a C# programmer (not the compiler write) assume that?

Comment: @Nawaz: For delegates, you can *absolutely* assume that you'll have different instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the types involved.

For all the reference types (ie. *classes*), *one* method will be JITted to handle them all.

For all the value types (ie. *structs*), *one* method **per** type will be JITted.

So the information in the question is not detailed enough to answer, if `Feature` and `Category` are reference types, then yes, one method will be JITted for them. If one of them, or both, are value types, one method per value type will be JITted.

Note my use of the word *JITted* here. In the assembly compiled, there will be only one method, but at runtime, the JITter will create actual implementations of the generic methods according to the above rules.

**Pop Quiz**: What happens if you use `NGEN` on an assembly with generic types/methods? (hint: [not what you think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644294/any-reason-why-ngen-should-hang-and-never-complete-for-a-particular-assembly/4122253#4122253))

Answer (score 5):

They all share a method *definition*, but at runtime they are different `MethodInfo` - because the generic type arguments **define** a generic method.

Supporting illustration:

```
    Action<FunArg> a1 = Fun<X>;
    Action<FunArg> a2 = Fun<Y>;
    Action<FunArg> a3 = Fun<Y>;
    Console.WriteLine(a1.Method == a2.Method); // false
    Console.WriteLine(a3.Method == a2.Method); // true
```

At the JIT level, it is more complex; any reference-type parameters will **share** an implementation, as a reference is a reference is a reference (noting that all such `T` must satisfy any constraints in advance). If there are value-type `T`, then every combination of generic type arguments gets a separate implementation at runtime, since each requires a different final implementation.

Comment: Isn't it simple at the IL level, but complex at the native (JIT-compiled) level?

Comment: I updated my question with more queries. Please that as well:-)

Comment: @Nawaz answered via a comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will become two separate methods.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: I may have to delete this answer by the way, because I wasn't looking too closely at the question.